# Spring.. why configuration in XML file format

Tags: spring, file, configuration, format

Why Spring uses the configuration in ".xml" file format,

Is there any possibility to configure in ".properties" file?

Comment: Why is the sky blue? Spring uses that because that's what they want to use. It could've been a .ini file, it could've been a .txt file - they chose .xml.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 3.0, and further enhanced in 3.1, Spring now has complete support for Java-based configuration.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Xml was the de-facto method of specifying configuration when Spring was in its infancy. As of spring3, it is possible to use annotations instead of xml.
However, you will still require to load the spring context first (using xml configuration file) and the rest of the spring based configuration would be loaded through the spring annotations.
Yes, you can specify the properties file separately for name-value pairs

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:filename.properties"/>
```